# Проблема с кавычками при формирование find()

Tags: yii2

Мне нужно сформировать следующий sql запрос

```
SELECT `searchjur`.*, `conditions`.* FROM `searchjur` LEFT JOIN `conditions` ON `searchjur`.`id` = `conditions`.`id_event` WHERE `conditions`.`id_jur` = 59  OR NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM searchjur  WHERE `conditions`.`id_event` = `searchjur`.`id`)
```

В yii2 я делаю следующее

```
$query = Searchjur::find()->select('searchjur.*, conditions.*');
        $query->joinWith(['conditions']);


        $query->where(['not exists', Searchjur::find()

                    ->where(['`conditions`.`id_event`' => 'searchjur.id'])]);


                $query->andWhere(['conditions.id_jur' => $id_jur]);

       return $query->createCommand()->getRawSql() ;
```

Проблема возникает с кавычками 
мне нужно на выходе

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

a yii делает 'searchjur.id' одинарные кавычки не косые

Профессионалы подскажите пожалуйста!
Ниже весь результ query в yii2

```
 "SELECT `searchjur`.*, `conditions`.* FROM `searchjur` LEFT JOIN `conditions` ON `searchjur`.`id` = `conditions`.`id_event` WHERE (NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM `searchjur` WHERE `conditions`.`id_event`='searchjur.id')) AND (`conditions`.`id_jur`=59)"
```

Answer (score 0):

Ну поменяйте

```
->where(['`conditions`.`id_event`' => 'searchjur.id'])
```

на это к примеру

```
->where('`conditions`.`id_event` = `searchjur`.`id`');
```

ведь $condition это string|array|Expression

Comment: Спасибо за ваш ответ.

Answer (score 0):

Сформулировал весь запрос в string со всей нужной мне пунктуации  и вставил его в where() Работает

$query = Searchjur::find()->select('searchjur.*, conditions.*');
            $query->joinWith(['conditions']);

```
        $query->where(['conditions.id_jur' => $id_jur]);
        $query->orWhere('NOT 
EXISTS (

SELECT * 
FROM searchjur
WHERE  `conditions`.`id_event` =  `searchjur`.`id`
)');
```